# Can't store a list of elements in Katalon to create assertions

Tags: java, groovy, ui-automation, katalon-studio, katalon

I'm studying Katalon for my Job and I'm having some problems !

Here is what I’m trying to do :

1 - Catch all the elements that matches the following xpath :

```
“//div[@class=‘price’]/div[@class=‘pricenew’] | //div[@class=‘price’]/div[@class=‘priceold’] | //div[@class=‘price’]/div[@class=‘oneprice’]”
```

2 - With that done and stored in an ArrayList variable , I wanna iterate through it and perform a check on each item to see if they have the correct symbol . For that , I have created a Keyword

```
 def checkElements(ArrayList<WebElement> list, String currency) {
    for (WebElement price : list) {
        String priceItem = WebUI.getText(list(price))
        if (WebUI.verifyElementText(priceItem, currency)) {
            continue
        } else {
            System.println("This item doesn't have the correct currency symbol")
        }
    }
   }
```

The thing is : I have tried using findElements , I have tried using findTestObject , but none of them works (It doesnt get the elements and store in an array)

My code look as following right now :

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

WebUI.openBrowser(‘https://automationteststore.com/’)

WebUI.maximizeWindow()

WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

List listPrices = driver.findElements(By.xpath(“//div[@class=‘price’]/div[@class=‘pricenew’] | //div[@class=‘price’]/div[@class=‘priceold’] | //div[@class=‘price’]/div[@class=‘oneprice’]”))

CustomKeywords.‘checkElement.checkElements’(listPrices, ‘$’)

WebUI.enhancedClick(findTestObject(‘Home_Page_Elements/dropdownToggle’))

WebUI.enhancedClick(findTestObject(‘Home_Page_Elements/dropdownPound’))

CustomKeywords.‘checkElement.checkElements’(listPrices, ‘£’)

WebUI.enhancedClick(findTestObject(‘Home_Page_Elements/dropdownEuro’))

CustomKeywords.‘checkElement.checkElements’(listPrices, ‘€’)

WebUI.enhancedClick(findTestObject(‘Home_Page_Elements/dropdownDollar’))

CustomKeywords.‘checkElement.checkElements’(listPrices, ‘$’)
```

The error I keep getting is :

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement) values: [[[CChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (28974eee30b54427ffbfcfa46388ac70)] -> xpath: //div[@class='price']/div[@class='pricenew'] | //div[@class='price']/div[@class='priceold'] | //div[@class='price']/div[@class='oneprice']]]
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks !

Catch all the elements given an xpath, store that in an ArrayList variable and perform assertions .